# Using WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 (id) FROM table WHERE aaa LIKE @aaa AND doesn't return results where without AND it does

Tags: c#, sql-server, where-clause

I'm using a C# program to transfer CSV data into a SQL Server Express database.
I'm using the following SQL string to try to ensure doubles aren't entered into the database.

```
"INSERT INTO Transacties (DebetRekening, CreditRekening, Datum, Bedrag, VolgNummer, Munt, Code, Betalingskenmerk, Omschrijving)
    SELECT 
        @DebetRekening, @CreditRekening, @Datum, @Bedrag, @VolgNummer, 
        @Munt, @Code, @Betalingskenmerk, @Omschrijving
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1(TransactieID)
                      FROM Transacties
                      WHERE DebetRekening LIKE @DebetRekening
                        AND CreditRekening LIKE @CreditRekening
                        AND Datum LIKE @Datum
                        AND Bedrag LIKE @Bedrag
                        AND VolgNummer LIKE @VolgNummer
                        AND Munt LIKE @Munt
                        AND Code LIKE @Code 
                        AND Betalingskenmerk LIKE @Betalingskenmerk 
                        AND Omschrijving LIKE @Omschrijving)"
```

Linebreaks added here to make it readable, it's a single line in the program.

Here I'm including a record, unless I can find this record in the database.

Even when I know the record I'm trying to enter is in the database, SQL cannot find it and just enters a double.

If I omit all the AND statements like so:

```
"INSERT INTO Transacties
(DebetRekening, CreditRekening, Datum, Bedrag, VolgNummer, Munt, Code, Betalingskenmerk, Omschrijving)
SELECT @DebetRekening, @CreditRekening, @Datum, @Bedrag, @VolgNummer, @Munt, @Code, @Betalingskenmerk, @Omschrijving
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT TOP 1(TransactieID)
FROM Transacties
WHERE
DebetRekening LIKE @DebetRekening
)"
```

It finds the existing record and doesn't enter it doubly.

It's regardless of which parameter I'm using, as long as there is only one.
As soon as I enter an AND to check another field it can't find any records anymore.

What am I missing here?

Comment: is any of the values null? Also use = instead of like. It may produce wrong results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, the problem is with `NULL` values. A condition like `Datum LIKE @Datum` is not fulfilled if any of the values is `NULL`.

You would need to check if both values are equal *or* are both `null`: that's the concept of null-safe equality (for which SQLServer has not built-in, unlike MySQL for example).

```
INSERT INTO Transacties(...)
SELECT ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Transacties
    WHERE
        (DebetRekening IS NULL AND @DebetRekening IS NULL OR DebetRekening = @DebetRekening)
        AND (CreditRekening IS NUL AND @CreditRekening IS NULL OR CreditRekening = @CreditRekening)
        AND ...
)
```

Notes:

- you don't need `SELECT TOP 1` in an `EXISTS` subquery; the `EXISTS` construct is there to check if *something* exists, and the database basically throws away the results immediatly. `SELECT 1` is a widely used convention
- `a LIKE b` is equivalent to `a = b` (since no wildcard is used on the right operand): I simplified your code accordingly
- depending on your database, better options may exists. For example, MySQL has `ON DUPLICATE KEYS`, Postgres has `ON CONFLICT`.